# How to abort a blocking process.getInputStream().read() with close()?

Tags: java

I'm trying to abort an already blocking InputStream.read() by closing the stream, but read() does not return.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sleep", "100000");
    Process process = builder.start();
    final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

    Thread worker = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int data;
                while ((data = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Read:" + data);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    worker.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    // process.destroy(); 
    is.close();
    worker.join();
}
```

**Is there some way to abort the already blocking read() by closing the stream, without invoking process.destroy()?**

The background to this question is a complex eclipse plugin that most of the time will abort a blocking BufferedReader.readLine() by calling process.destroy(), but sometimes readLine() is not aborted. I suspect some race with the JVM internal ProcessReaper thread and I'm trying to working around that by closing the stream explicitly.

I'm using Linux and JDK 1.7.0_25-b15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried `close()` and it doesn't work.  The only other thing I can think of to try is calling `Thread.interrupt()` on the blocked thread ... but I doubt that that will work either.

The real issue is that the specs (i.e. respective javadocs) don't say whether these things will work.  Even if they do work ... for some version of Java on some OS platform ... there is no guarantee that they will work on other version/platform combinations.

Comment: In short, you are stuck.  I think you will need to figure out what is really happening with that problem that you were attempting to work around.

Comment: I found more info about the background problem: "Behaviour of InputStream of a destroyed process is not specified/guaranteed. One should not try reading from InputStream of a process, after the process has been destroyed." (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4311711.) As a workaround I'm planning to redirect the subprocess stdout to a file and read non-blocking from the file.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, new answer.  The [NuProcess](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/NuProcess) library implements non-blocking I/O for processes, so you can avoid this situation altogether.

*Disclaimer: I am the author of NuProcess.*

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something similar and in my case it turned out that every time when a java thread would block, it was because the child process has given the file descriptor to its own child, which was still alive after `Process.destroy()` was called. So, schematically it looks like this:

```
java thread --> child process --> grandchild process
```

I actually did go and check the source code of `Process.destroy()` for Windows and Linux platforms, and it turned out a `kill 9` command is executed. If it was to kill a grandchild, a `kill -9` command would be necessary. I am not aware of any good way to solve this issue without using JNI, but since you write for Eclipse, you can try luck with [CDT Spawner](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/utils/org/eclipse/cdt/utils/spawner/Spawner.java) class instead of `java.lang.Runtime`. I recall it provided some features beyond Runtime, but don't recall if it could solve this issue. This class is for example used to launch and debug native processes by Eclipse CDT environment.

Bug [JDK-4770092](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4770092) provides an explanation why it is difficult to kill grandchild processes on Windows. As far as I understand, Sun/Oracle decided to provide the lowest common denominator, and that's why no grandchildren are killed on Unix either.

On a second thought, if I was wrong and Process.destroy() sends a SIGTERM, the following shell script should isolate all subprocesses from java, and would work both on Linux and in Cygwin on Windows.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Initialize variables
program="$1"; shift
child_pid=0

# Register a signal handler procedure
signalHandler() {
    echo "Sending SIGKILL to process $child_pid and all its children"
    [0 = $child_pid] || kill -9 -$child_pid
    echo "Removing temporary folder: $tmp_folder"
    rm -fr "$tmp_folder"
}
trap signalHandler 0 1 2 3 15

# Create a temporary folder
tmp_folder=$(mktemp -d --quiet)

# Launch a child process in background
program "$@" >$(tmp_folder)/somefile 2>&1 &

# Remember the subprocess id
child_pid=$!

# Make tail exit when the subprocess exits
# Maybe, this is a bad idea. I haven’t tested it
# If it doesn't work, one can read from file with Java NIO
tail --follow --pid=$child_pid $(tmp_folder)/somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which I solved by checking a number of available bytes before reading from the stream.
Modifying your example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sleep", "100000");
    Process process = builder.start();
    final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    final AtomicBoolean stopReading = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    final long CHECK_INTERVAL = 100; // msec.

    Thread worker = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                workerLoop:
                while (true) {
                    int availableBytes = is.available(); // this call should be non-blocking
                    if (availableBytes > 0) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[availableBytes];
                        int c = is.read(buffer); // this call should be non-blocking
                        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
                            if (buffer[i] == -1) // standard check for the end of stream
                            {
                                break workerLoop;
                            }
                            // do something with the data....
                        }                        
                    } else if (stopReading.get()) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(CHECK_INTERVAL);
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    worker.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    stopReading.set(true); // request to terminate the thread
    worker.join();
    is.close();
}
```

It is possible to modify the code to interrupt the worker thread instead of using a boolean flag.

I'm using Windows 10 and Oracle Java 8.

Comment: Why do you need  `buffer[i] == -1` to check the end of the stream?

Comment: @Bomin It is required since `java.io.InputStream.available()` returns an estimate and not an exact number. See [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--)

Answer (score -1):

I guess I can't say for sure in Java 1.7, but I have done this in Java 1.6.  You need 3 threads:

- The thread to read the stream
- A monitor thread to monitor the reading thread
- The main thread (gets created automatically for you, but I just want to be sure we don't forget about it.)

The reading thread should update a reference shared between it and the monitor thread, but more importantly, *the monitor needs to have a reference to the reading thread.*  The reading thread updates a time value on every read.  The monitor sleeps for a set time, and each time it wakes up, it checks that time stamp.  If the difference between the previous time and current time exceeds some value, the monitor forces an interrupt on the reading thread and then stops itself as well.

This could conceivably be done with only two threads -- the Main and the Monitor, where the main thread will be doing the reading and does `monitor.setReaderThread(Thread.currentThread()); monitorThread.start()`.  But I have only done this with three threads.

Comment: How can the monitor thread force an interrupt on the reading thread? Neither Thread.interrupt() nor InputStream.close() seems to work.

Comment: The monitor needs to have a reference to the reading thread.  From within the monitor, it calls `readingThread.interrupt()` and then exits.

Comment: You are trying to call `close` and `interrupt` from the thread that is hung, which is impossible.  That's why you need the monitor to do it.

Comment: close/interrupt is not called from the thread that is hung, read the example code in the question again.

Comment: All I can tell you is that this works for me.  Part of the issue *might* be that both threads have a handle to the stream.  Since the underlying stream behavior is platform dependent, it's difficult to tell what the impact will be.